# Finding specific syntactic combinations in a tagged text (Python, TreeTagger)

Tags: computational-linguistics

I am trying to write a python program that can 1) tag a text using TreeTagger, and 2) identify certain syntactic combinations within the tagged text.

I've got TreeTagger up and running in python; it tags texts just fine. However, I have no idea how to get my program to identify instances of, say, a 'DT' (determiner) that is followed by an 'NN' (noun), for example. I am NOT looking for a specific string; I am simply looking to identify certain syntactic combinations.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I've made some progress! However, I'm getting an error:import treetaggerwrapper, re, nltk, pprint as p

T = open('5114.male.25.indUnk.Scorpio.xml','r')
text = T.read()
split_text = re.split('\W+', text)
T2 = open('5114.male.25.indUnk.Scorpio.TAGGED.xml','w')


tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG = 'en')
tags = tagger.tag_text(split_text)

tagged_text = T2.write(str(tags))
    
for (w1, t1), (w2, t2) in nltk.trigrams(tags):
    if (t1.startwith('DET')) and (t2.startwith('NN')) :
       print(w1, w2)